# Dynamically set both throttle and timePeriodMillis in Camel

Tags: apache-camel, throttling

I am new to Camel and trying to implement a requirement as below

from("seda://requestCamel").throttle(ExpressionBuilder.beanExpression(CamelHandler.getInstance(),"getTransactionsPerMillie")).timePeriodMillis(CamelHandler.getTimeInMillie()).bean(service, "callCamel(${body})");

From the above expression both the values (throttle and timePeriodMillis) required to change dynamically at run time. Using bean expression I could able to manage for throttle however timePeriodMillis does not accept real time values. Any help/work around would be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the time period millis at runtime - its a fixed value in the current implementation of the throttler in Apache Camel.

Comment: Thanks Claus for the response. Would it be possible to refresh a route each time with new values for throttle and timePeriodMillis. If I can, is there any side impacts.

Comment: No that would be a bad idea as the throttler would have state and throttling some messages. Are you sure you are not misusing a throttler for a delayer? With a delayer you can delay each message individually computed from a bean

Comment: Thanks for the update. Delayer may work too for my use case. I think I am clear on my use case. Requirement : User will provide input as how many messages he/she want to process in some time window. E.g 1st User provides 1000 messages to process in 5 min. 2nd user provides 2000 messages in 5 min and so on. I have one camel context and a single route. Could you please show some lights.

Comment: Second requirement is to enable throttle on the route so that it won't overload the server anytime. Today I set 10k per hour but tomorrow it may change to 7k per 30 mins...and this will override user input request. if crossed the maximum threshold values.. Thought both can be solved using throttle. Bit confused what and how to use. Please help me on this